# Lua: table.remove does not work with 2D array

Tags: arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, lua

```
t = { 
  { 7, "123" }, 
  { 8, "234" }, 
  { 9, "345" }
}

t = table.remove(t, 1) -- This thing brokes everything, but should delete first group

for k, v in ipairs(t) do
  print(k, v[1], v[2])
end
```

This thing just hates me, I fighting with it for 4 hours and ca not move from dead point. Tried several different loops, different letters positions (`v[1] -> k[1]`, etc), nothing helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table.remove` returns the removed element, not the updated table.  Just don't assign `t = table.remove(t, 1)` but instead discard the return value, i.e. a bare `table.remove(t, 1)` without any assignment.

See also [the manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.remove):

> #### table.remove (table [, pos])
>
> Removes from table the element at position `pos`, shifting down other elements to close the space, if necessary. Returns the value of the removed element. The default value for `pos` is `n`, where `n` is the length of the table, so that a call `table.remove(t)` removes the last element of table `t`.

```
t = { 
  { 7, "123" }, 
  { 8, "234" }, 
  { 9, "345" }
}

table.remove(t, 1)

for k, v in pairs(t) do
  print(k, v[1], v[2])
end
```

Comment: You are lifesaver, man. Omfg, I didn't thought it will make a thing without assign. Now all works like a charm, as it intended in begining. Thank you much.